# 2009Ax Customization : The system should give the flexibility of creating RFQ from Item requirement form in project module

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, ax

I have created a form in that i have created ok,cancel,and validate button and when i click ok button  an infolog popup should open and  required data should come there and when i click cancel and validate also it should perform it's actions  for this what code i have to write for ok , cancel and validate button  or is there any other way to do it with out code..
 Can any one plz helpme out...

Answer (score 0):

To pass a reference to the data between forms please read the following blog entry, [passing parameters between forms in AX](http://mfmujahidmim.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/passing-parameters-between-forms-in-ax/)

> Override the *init* method on opened form
>   and you get the parent dataset records as
>
> element.args().record()

Comment: Hi Ian_scho, Thanks for the reply.. still the data is not passing from the opened form after clicking ok button.. the code written for ok button i.e., clicked() is having error...